# How many ways to solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE  $\quad y''-y=0$. I can think of a couple solution techniques that will produce the general solution.

1. Exponential Method - $y(x) = e^{rx}$
2. Power Series - $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nx^n$
3. Energy Method - multiply through by $y'$ and then solve the first order equation.

What other elementary or clever solution techniques are available for this?

What an excellent review problem for BC Calculus - exponentials, hyperbolics, trig sub, hyperbolic sub, eigenvalues & eigenvectors , improper integration, partial fractions, power series. Thx for all of your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let $u = y'(x)$

$\implies u'(x) = y''(x)$

$\implies u'(x)-y(x)=0 \implies u(x)=\int y(x) dx$

Then use $y=\int u(x) dx$ to get the final solution.

Comment: Why is it not $u'(x) = \int u(x) dx$?

Comment: @JohnLou There was a mistake, fixed now I think.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to differential equations, but how would you find the general solution from the last step?